# How can i upload video on specific channel using YouTube API in PHP?

Tags: php, youtube, access-token, youtube-data-api

I want to make functionality for users to upload video on my channel without authentication (if needed). IS it possible ?

Please help me .

Thanks 
OM

Answer (score 2):

Yes Omprakash,it is possible

1. You will need Google APIs Client Library for PHP.
2. You will also need to create a project on
   https://console.developers.google.com/ and get credentials(i.e
   client secret & client id).
3. Finally,you will need to generate access token for specific channel.
   Please take a  look at this link
   (https://youtube-eng.googleblog.com/2013/06/google-page-identities-and-youtube-api_24.html)
   to generate access token.
4. Once you have all these things ready with you,you can use ready made
   example code available in Google APIs Client Library for PHP to upload
   video on YouTube.

Note: This is not in detail process.It is not possible to explain all of the process in detail on stack-overflow. But, once you get close to solution,you can re-post or put comment for further assistance.

This is example code to upload video on YouTube. Hope, it will help you

```
/*include google libraries */
require_once '../api/src/Google/autoload.php';
require_once '../api/src/Google/Client.php';
require_once '../api/src/Google/Service/YouTube.php';

$application_name = 'Your application/project name created on google developer console'; 
$client_secret = 'Your client secret';
$client_id = 'Your client id';
$scope = array('https://www.googleapis.com/auth/youtube.upload', 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/youtube', 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/youtubepartner');


    try{ 
        $key = file_get_contents('the_key.txt'); //it stores access token obtained in step 3
        $videoPath = 'video path on your server goes here';
        $videoTitle = 'video title';
        $videoDescription = 'video description';
        $videoCategory = "22"; //please take a look at youtube video categories for videoCategory.Not so important for our example
        $videoTags = array('tag1', 'tag2','tag3');  

        // Client init
        $client = new Google_Client();
        $client->setApplicationName($application_name);
        $client->setClientId($client_id);
        $client->setAccessType('offline');
        $client->setAccessToken($key);
        $client->setScopes($scope);
        $client->setClientSecret($client_secret);

        if ($client->getAccessToken()) {
            /**
             * Check to see if our access token has expired. If so, get a new one and save it to file for future use.
             */
            if($client->isAccessTokenExpired()) {
                $newToken = json_decode($client->getAccessToken());
                $client->refreshToken($newToken->refresh_token);
                file_put_contents('the_key.txt', $client->getAccessToken());
            }

            $youtube = new Google_Service_YouTube($client);



            // Create a snipet with title, description, tags and category id
            $snippet = new Google_Service_YouTube_VideoSnippet();
            $snippet->setTitle($videoTitle);
            $snippet->setDescription($videoDescription);
            $snippet->setCategoryId($videoCategory);
            $snippet->setTags($videoTags);

            // Create a video status with privacy status. Options are "public", "private" and "unlisted".
            $status = new Google_Service_YouTube_VideoStatus();
            $status->setPrivacyStatus('public');

            // Create a YouTube video with snippet and status
            $video = new Google_Service_YouTube_Video();
            $video->setSnippet($snippet);
            $video->setStatus($status);

            // Size of each chunk of data in bytes. Setting it higher leads faster upload (less chunks,
            // for reliable connections). Setting it lower leads better recovery (fine-grained chunks)
            $chunkSizeBytes = 1 * 1024 * 1024;

            // Setting the defer flag to true tells the client to return a request which can be called
            // with ->execute(); instead of making the API call immediately.
            $client->setDefer(true);

            // Create a request for the API's videos.insert method to create and upload the video.
            $insertRequest = $youtube->videos->insert("status,snippet", $video);

            // Create a MediaFileUpload object for resumable uploads.
            $media = new Google_Http_MediaFileUpload(
                $client,
                $insertRequest,
                'video/*',
                null,
                true,
                $chunkSizeBytes
            );
            $media->setFileSize(filesize($videoPath));


            // Read the media file and upload it chunk by chunk.
            $status = false;
            $handle = fopen($videoPath, "rb");
            while (!$status && !feof($handle)) {
                $chunk = fread($handle, $chunkSizeBytes);
                $status = $media->nextChunk($chunk);
            }

            fclose($handle);

            /**
             * Video has successfully been upload, now lets perform some cleanup functions for this video
             */
            if ($status->status['uploadStatus'] == 'uploaded') {
                $youtube_id = $status->id; //you got here youtube video id 
            } else {
                // handle failere here
            }

            // If you want to make other calls after the file upload, set setDefer back to false
            $client->setDefer(true);

        } else{
            // @TODO Log error
            echo 'Problems creating the client';
        }

    } catch(Google_Service_Exception $e) {
        echo  "\r\n Caught Google service Exception ".$e->getCode(). " message is ".$e->getMessage();
        echo "\r\n Stack trace is ".$e->getTraceAsString(); 
    } catch (Exception $e) {
        echo  "\r\n Caught Google service Exception ".$e->getCode(). " message is ".$e->getMessage();
        echo  "\r\n Stack trace is ".$e->getTraceAsString(); 
    }
```

Comment: I have done already following steps as you mentioned: - 

1) 
2)
3)
4)

And my video uploaded successfully on Youtube , but i want to upload on specific channel OR Specific Account.  for now user uploading video on their youtube account.

Comment: In step 3, access token is mentioned.Access token is required to upload videos on YouTube. You are collecting this access token from user. That's why videos are getting uploaded to their channel.Instead, you should create your own access token as mentioned in provided link in step 3.This access token expires after some time (I.e. say 1 hour).You need to refresh it periodically.

Comment: Thanks a lot Dinesh , Let me try as per given link in step 3

Comment: @Dinesh Belakare  Here where you have specified that video will be uploaded to specific channel. Like one user has more than one channel and user want to upload video on channel one. How its possible?

Comment: @Ranjit..
 In the above process,channel owner access token(ontime) is generated manually and stored in separate file("the_key.txt").
While generating this access token you have to choose specific channel.
So, code does not handle channel selection, it is "access token" which takes care which channel to select while uploading videos.
Let me know if you have any doubt.

Comment: @DineshBelakare you mean if I pass access token in code for any channel then it will upload video to that channel. is it Correct?